# Java ServerSocket and Socket to implement an IM System

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I'm trying to implement a small LAN IM System in Java. And I have a KDC(Key Distribution Center) for dispatching session keys to users. Here's a picture about my initial design:
[image] 
**Steps** about chatting with a logged-in user: 
(Two users, A and B) 
1. `A` send request to `KDC` says that he wants to talk with `B` 
2. `KDC` forward request to `B` 
3. `B` accepts or denies the request 
4. If `B` accepts, `KDC` will send `A`'s public key to `B` and `B`'s public key to `A`, Else send null
5. `A` and `B` generate a secret key to chat with each other 
Now my **questions**:
I use `ServerSocket` to implement `KDC`. It will manage and dispatch public keys. I use `Socket` to implement `User`, and I know how to let a `User` communicate with `KDC` but I don't know how to let a `User` communicate with another `User`. So I have to use both `Socket` and `ServerSocket` to implement `User`? And if `A` talks with two or more other users at the same time. How to deal with the `sockets` and `server sockets` in a `User`?

Comment: Not related with your question but, unless you are doing it to learn something or for fun, why don't you use a jabber/xmpp server? This problem is already solved.

Comment: @GuidoGarcía It's my homework of Information Security but not a practical application :)

Comment: UserA will send a message to server, server than route the message to UserB. You have to come-up with a protocol obviously. The other option is to forward IP details of User A to User B (or vice versa) and initiate the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously the server must push messages to users (the forwarded requests). Therefore, either the user keeps a permanent socket connection open to the server, or the user must be ready to accept new connections from the server.

For the first option, you could route all messages between users via the server, i.e. much as the server negotiates the original requests, it also distributes the messages. Advantage: The infrastructure is relatively simple, you can handle requests and messages with the same logic, and distributing messages to multiple users is easy. Obvious disadvantage: The server becomes a bottleneck for all messages, and security-wise it will see all messages.

The second option means that, yes, each User must have a ServerSocket in order to accept incoming connections, as well as initiating outgoing connections via Sockets. In this scenario, you must find a reliable way of negotiating who contacts whom. A natural solution would be to have the User which sends a chat request to also connect via a Socket to the ServerSocket of the other User. Advantage: Messages can pass directly between users. Disadvantage: Much more complicated infrastructure, especially when multiple users chat with each other. And it's not more failsafe than the centralized server solution, as it still requires the server for handling requests.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think you should implement it by netty-socketio,in you scenario,KDC should known each node,but each node no need to known others,so the key function of KDC is routing message.
try use socketio replace io you will got a better performace!
netty-socketio 's link as shown below!
https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio